In the context of {ARG_MAX}, how robust is `find . -exec sh -c 'exec tool "$@" extra-arg' find-sh {} +`?
Suppose I want to do this:
find . -exec tool {} extra-arg +

It doesn't work and I know why: -exec … {} + does not allow extra-arg(s) between {} and +. So be it. It seems I can inject the extra-arg by using a shell, like this:
find . -exec sh -c 'exec tool "$@" extra-arg' find-sh {} +

My question is: how robust is this method? I mean in the context of {ARG_MAX} and possible "argument list too long" error. I know find … -exec … {} + is supposed to group pathnames in sets to avoid the error. At first glance the command from the expansion of tool "$@" extra-arg should be shorter than what find executes, so if find manages to avoid "argument list too long" then exec tool … will avoid it as well; but:

I'm not sure if the relevant structure will contain tool or /full/absolute/path/to/tool which may be long and thus possibly make the structure exceed {ARG_MAX}, despite the effort to not exceed {ARG_MAX} taken by find earlier.

I'm not sure if sh may add something to the relevant structure and thus possibly make the structure exceed {ARG_MAX}, despite the effort to not exceed {ARG_MAX} taken by find earlier.


Assuming that find does a good job avoiding "argument list too long", can I assume my exec tool … invoked in the inner shell will avoid the error as well?
Clarification:

Yes, I'm asking about my attempted solution, like in the XY problem; but I'm deliberately asking about my attempted solution because I want to understand possible flaws of it. I know I can use -exec tool {} extra-arg \; and avoid the problem. I know I can pipe (preferably null-terminated strings) to xargs and let xargs deal with {ARG_MAX}. If my attempted solution is not robust and if some improvement can make it robust then I'm interested, but only if -exec … {} + is kept.
I know that some implementations of find do not try to get as close to {ARG_MAX} as possible, but according to the POSIX specification find does not have to leave any room we could take advantage of later. I do not have any particular implementation of find in mind. In this matter I will appreciate generic answers or answers that compare many implementations.
In the context of (1), the question is specifically about Linux. If a good answer mentions or compares to other Unices then fine, I don't mind extending the scope this way; but I do not require this.
In the context of (2), I do not have any particular implementation of sh in mind.


In any case, there's nothing stopping a file path as reported by find to be bigger than ARG_MAX (or the single argument limit of Linux), though if it's longer than ARG_MAX, it wil also likely be longer than PATH_MAX, so chances are tool won't be able to do anything with it.

FWIW on Ubuntu 22.04 I can get GNU or busybox find to fail to execute even sh (let alone sh to execute tool) with just limit stacksize 1M

find's -n option can limit the number of arguments to well below ARG_MAX. See man find.

@waltinator, what find implementation would that be? I don't see any such option with that of GNU or BSDs. Are you not confusing with xargs?

@StéphaneChazelas yes, I was. The xargs -n switch limits arguments.

When I find myself trying to stretch find too much, I wrap the complicated bits in a bash script, and just use  find and xargs to call the script with the filenames.
